# JavaScript Drag-n-Drop shows an arrow icon on Edge Browser

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, rubaxa-sortable

I am creating a POC for Drag-n-Drop using JavaScript HTML5. But on **Edge** browser facing a weird issue i.e. it displays an "arrow" icon while dragging the html element.

Version Details: 
*Microsoft Edge 38.14393.0.0 / Microsoft EdgeHTML 14.14393*

```
Drag-n-Drop Behavior:  https://codepen.io/kcak11/pen/zPgyBq
```

[image]

**Note:** This doesn't happen on any other browser like IE, Chrome, Firefox, Safari. Its only the Edge browser that is displaying this little arrow.
Is there any way to disable this via code ?

Please provide suggestions.

(Thanks in advance)

The issue is still not resolved as of 2019-September-26.

Comment: you can find the answer of your question in this link :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57047735/is-it-possible-to-hide-the-additional-icon-when-dragging-an-element-in-microsoft

Comment: hmm, I was actually trying to completely get rid of that icon, looks like Edge does not accept that & I have to live with it. Thanks anyways @SamerCherif